# I'm getting a "Must Declare Scalar Variable" error when inserting from python

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

Here is my code. I'm trying to insert data from a CSV into a SQL Server Table. I'm trying to follow what seems like a relatively simple example here:
https://datatofish.com/import-csv-sql-server-python/

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Steve\Documents\Datasets\covidgeography.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['MMSA', 'total_percent_at_risk', 'high_risk_per_ICU_bed', 'high_risk_per_hospital',
                                 'icu_beds', 'hospitals', 'total_at_risk'])
print(df)

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=STEVELAPTOP;'
                      'Database=AdventureWorks2017;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor()

#cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE dbo.covidgeo(MMSA nvarchar(250),total_percent_at_risk nvarchar(250),'
#               'high_risk_per_ICU_bed nvarchar(250), '
#               'high_risk_per_hospital nvarchar(250),icu_beds nvarchar(250),hospitals nvarchar(250),total_at_risk '
#               'nvarchar(250))')
for row in df.itertuples():
    cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO AdventureWorks2017.dbo.covidgeo(MMSA,total_percent_at_risk,high_risk_per_ICU_bed,
    high_risk_per_hospital,icu_beds,hospitals,total_at_risk) VALUES (???????) 
    ''',
                   row.MMSA,
                   row.total_percent_at_risk,
                   row.high_risk_per_ICU_bed,
                   row.high_risk_per_hospital,
                   row.icu_beds,
                   row.hospitals,
                   row.total_at_risk)
    conn.commit()
```

After I run this I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Steve\PycharmProjects\DataLearning\DataImport.py", line 20, in <module>
    cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO AdventureWorks2017.dbo.covidgeo(MMSA,total_percent_at_risk,high_risk_per_ICU_bed,
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Must declare the scalar variable "@P1@P2@P3@P4@P5@P6@P7". (137) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)')
```

Do I have a syntax error in how I'm writing the insert statement?

Comment: Hint: `... VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) `, not `... VALUES (???????) `.

Comment: You are developing BAD habits. Your connection determines the database. Do NOT use 3 part names for your objects (e.g., table, stored procedure) without a very good reason. Only reference tables as "schema.table".

Answer (score 0):

It was a syntax error. I had to change:

```
VALUES (???????)
```

to

```
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```